# Trying to copy and paste using byobu

Tags: tmux

byobu is great but i am finding it very difficult to copy and paste in it.Is there a way to copy and paste by using the mouse in byobu, or a way for me to configure it to give me what i want.

Thanks

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?